# Python import module load_source

Tags: python

I have question on the load_source.

when my 2 `.py` files are in the same directory `/home/pi` they work fine.

main.py

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import buttonlog
```

buttonlog.py

```
import datetime
i = datetime.datetime.now()

#OPEN FILE & APPEND
f=open('buttonlog.txt','a')
#WRITE DATE THEN NEW LINE WITH THE '\N'
f.write(i.isoformat() + '\n')
```

When I run python main.py it writes an entry like I'd expect. 
However I'd like to store `main.py` in another directory so I tried this, it is stored in the `/home/pi/test`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import imp
imp.load_source('buttonlog', '/home/pi/buttonlog.py')
```

When I run python `/home/pi/test/main.py` I do not get any errors nor does it write an entry into my file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I bet it does append a time entry into `/home/pi/test/buttonlog.txt`, though...

Comment: Dang! I missed that. How can I get it to write to the other? Add the path to my buttonlog.py?

Comment: Yes, put the full path name in the open() call if you always want the file written to a specific place (vs the current working directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is the use of the [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) command.

As the documentation says about the first argument,

> file is a [path-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object) giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or an integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped.

By passing just `"buttonlog.txt"`, this is not an absolute pathname, so it's relative to the current working directory.

The simplest way to fix this is to use a full path.  If you always want it writing in to `/home/pi`, you just need:

```
f=open('/home/pi/buttonlog.txt','a')
```

There are other alternatives, though I think this is the cleanest.  You could also change your current working directory prior to issuing the open command for the same results.  Simply put this code above the `open` line:

```
import os
os.chdir("/home/pi")
```